# Why this code still adding rows to the table if indexOf return 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I've this jQuery that allow to add new rows to a table on click event of a button but only if the `id` value isn't already added.

```
var factAgregada = [];

$('#btnAgregarFactura').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // no_factura and fecha_factura comes from a modal window 
    // it's not relevant to show that part here

    var no_factura = $("#no_factura").val(), 
        fecha_factura = $("#fecha_factura").val(),
        html;

    console.log(no_factura);
    console.log(factAgregada.indexOf(no_factura));

    if (factAgregada.indexOf(no_factura) >= -1) {
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="' + no_factura + '"></td>';
        html += '<td>' + no_factura + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + fecha_factura + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $(html).appendTo("#facturaBody");
    }

    factAgregada.push(no_factura);
});
```

On first execution the code works fine and `console.log()` outputs this:

```
 12
 -1
```

So it's right add the row, but on second execution and keeping the same value `console.log()` changes from the previos values to this ones:

```
12
0
```

So, row shouldn't be added but still adding to the table and continue doing the `appendTo()`, what's wrong there? What I'm not seeing?

Comment: have you tried just '=='

Comment: @shaN tried right now and not works

Comment: if not in array indexOf returns -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var factAgregada = [];

$('#btnAgregarFactura').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var no_factura = 10, 
        fecha_factura = 2,
        html;

    console.log(no_factura);
    console.log(factAgregada.indexOf(no_factura));

    if (factAgregada.indexOf(no_factura) == -1) {
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="' + no_factura + '"></td>';
        html += '<td>' + no_factura + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + fecha_factura + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';

       console.log(html);
    }

    factAgregada.push(no_factura);
});
```

change condition checking

[view this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu5bfso/)

Comment: Thanks now it works so simple and I was looking for the 2k0 error (just jooking)

Answer (score 1):

a more elegant way of writing it may be `if (!$("#" + no_factura)[0] )`

checks if no such element with id exists, only then it adds...